# Kubernetes -env and -envFrom environment variables setting

Tags: kubernetes

Can Kubernetes deployment manifest file have both -env and -envFrom keys?

I have set a `secrets.yaml` file to set the environment variables and also have environment variables that are hard coded.

Can I have both of them set using both `-env` and `-envFrom` in the YAML files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Can kubernetes deployment manifest file have both -env and -envFrom keys?`

Yes.

```
...
envFrom:
- secretRef:
    name: <name of your secret>
env:
- name: <variable name>
  value: <hardcoded value>

- name: <variable name>
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: <name of your secret>
      key: <If I only want this and not all the keys in the secret>
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes, and you can simply try it out.....

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: codewizard
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: codewizard-configmap
  namespace: codewizard
data:
  APP_ENV: production
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: codewizard-busybox
  namespace: codewizard
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busybox
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: busybox
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: busybox
        image: busybox
        command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
        args: [ "while true; do printenv; done;" ]
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: codewizard-configmap
        env:
        - name: OS
          value: Linux
```

- Now check the pod's log and you will see all the env values

```bash
kubectl exec \
    -n codewizard \
    $(kubectl get pods -n codewizard -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') \
    -- sh -c "printenv"
```

[image]